# Groovy's HTTPBuilder for Java?

Tags: java, http, groovy, httpbuilder

Is there an equivalent of [Groovy's HTTPBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/index.html) for Java?

Comment: Does [HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/) work for you?

Comment: I'm using HTTPClient right now.  HTTPBuilder is a wrapper around HTTPClient.  I want to try it in my project because it provides built in xml and json parser support and different mechanism to create and manipulate uri's.  I am not using any specific framework.

Comment: Correction, I'm not tied to any specific framework.

Answer (score 1):

Add groovy support to your existing project and use Groovy's HTTPBuilder

http://briantarbox.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/tutorial-for-adding-groovy-to-java.html

"Overall this should take no more than twenty minutes or so."